# Will all cores in a multi-core processor share control registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture

I read the introduction of the CR0.CD flag in both the AMD and Intel manuals and get the following 2 questions:

1. Does the setting of CR0 affect all cores? In other words, does each core have a separate set of control registers?
2. Does setting the CD flag to 1 only disable the internal caches, or the external caches also disabled as well? The interpretation of Intel and AMD are different.

Comment: You are really asking two different questions here.  As for (1), each core has its own set of registers and does not affect the others.  As for (2), I don't know.

Comment: @fuz: minor caveat: `CR0.CD` is per *physical* core; logical cores sharing the same physical core *are* all affected when one of them executes a `mov cr0, rax`.  [How to explicitly load a structure into L1d cache? Weird results with INVD with CR0.CD = 1 on isolated core with/without hyperthreading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66772632) shows the consequences of that for messing around with `invd` and no-fill mode.  But yes, otherwise control registers are per-logical-core, and definitely not shared across physical cores.